# Changing fonts using Javascript in eex templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, elixir

I have some Javascript that changes fonts on select:

```
console.clear();

    var fontsArr = ['Josefin Sans',  'Raleway', 'Montserrat', 'Crimson Text', 'Special Elite', 'Alegreya Sans', 'Cardo', 'Playfair Display', 'Poppins', 'PT Sans']

var $fontSelector = $('.font-selector select');
var $preview = $('.preview-title');
var $fontTextSelector = $('.font-selector-text select');
var $previewText = $('.preview-text');

$fontSelector.on('change', function() {
  $(this).css({
    fontFamily: $(this).val()
  });
  $preview.css({
    fontFamily: $(this).val()
  });
});

$fontTextSelector.on('change', function() {
  $(this).css({
    fontFamily: $(this).val()
  });
  $previewText.css({
    fontFamily: $(this).val()
  });
});

_.forEach(fontsArr, function(fontName, index){
  var $option = $('<option style="font-family:'+fontName+'">'+fontName+'</option>');
  $fontSelector.append($option);
});

_.forEach(fontsArr, function(fontName, index){
  var $option = $('<option style="font-family:'+fontName+'">'+fontName+'</option>');
  $fontTextSelector.append($option);
});

$fontSelector.trigger('change');

WebFont.load({
  google: {
    families: fontsArr
  }
});
```

I loaded JQuery and Lodash as dependencies. I know the script works because I can change my html display font by inserting the correct class and selecting a font from the JS array:

```
<div class="preview-title">Select Title Font </div>

<div class="preview-text">Select Text Font</div>
```

The above lines are OK. If I add the preview-text class to a button it works:

```
<span><%= link "What's Up ?", to: post_path(@conn, :new), class: "whats-happening-button preview-text" %></span>
```

But adding the class to this line has no effect:

```
<p class="display-post-body preview-text"><%= post.body %></p>
```

I wrapped the line in div tags, also no effect:

```
 <div class="preview-text">
      <p class="display-post-body preview-text"><%= post.body %></p>
      </div>
```

Why is it working for some classes and not others?

I tried adding the class within the Elixir script:

```
<%= post.body, class: "preview-text" %>
```

But it raises a syntax error...

What's the correct way to add a class to post.body?

Comment: Can you check in the browser console whether there is some text inside the div with that class and that your JS code is picking up those elements? I don't see any reason why the `<p>` wouldn't work if the `<span><%= link ...` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was CSS !important declarations over-riding the JS font selection.

```
.display-post-body {
    /*Main index page */
    height: auto;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: 'Raleway'!important;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-left: 2px;
    line-height: 35px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

I took the !important in the display-post-body class away, and the font selection worked fine.

Answer (score -3):

```
Aspx page 

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ddlFont").change(function () {
                debugger;
                $(".changeMe").css("font-family", $(this).val());

            });

            $("#ddlsize").change(function () {
                debugger;
                $(".changeMe").css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
            });
        });
</script>
</head>


<table>
                <tr>
                    <td>OutPut</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="exampe">
                            <textarea name="TextBox1" class="changeMe" rows="2" id="TextBox1" cols="20"></textarea>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>change Font</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFont" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>change font</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlsize" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>


Code behind

  #region Fonts
            InstalledFontCollection fonts = new InstalledFontCollection();
            try
            {
                foreach (FontFamily font in fonts.Families)
                {
                    ddlFont.Items.Add(font.Name);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }

            #endregion


            #region SiZe

            try
            {
                for (int i =8; i < 50; i++)
                {
                    ddlsize.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }

            #endregion
```